# How to retain Magento customer session throughout all pages?

Tags: magento, session

I am creating customer login using custom php code. I am using API calls for creating the frontend, so I need to maintain the logged in session values throughtout all the pages once the customer has logged in.

Code in a.php

```
require_once "../magento/app/Mage.php";
Mage::app('default');
umask(0);
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

$session->start();
if (!empty($email) && !empty($password )) {
    try {
        $a = $session->login($email, $password );
        $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn( $session->getCustomer() );
        if ($session->getCustomer()->getIsJustConfirmed()) {
            $this->_welcomeCustomer($session->getCustomer(), true);
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to log in using this code but I need to maintain this logged in session throughout all the pages.

I tried to get the logged in user information from other page. But I can't.

Code in b.php

```
require_once "../magento/app/Mage.php";
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$session->start();
var_dump(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn());


if($session->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo 'User logged In';
} else {
    echo 'User not logged In';
}
```

After calling the page a.php and when I call b.php in the same browser, I need the customer information of the user logged in using a.php? Is that possible? Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```html
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
     $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
      echo $customerData->getId();
 }
```

Comment: getCustomer()
Call this function at the end

Comment: Hi Hassan Ali Shahzad, 

Its working ..!! :) Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: In chrome may be cache issue.
If its working then please select the answer and rank up for me :-)

Comment: @user3755732 if hassan's solution is working then you should give them upvote

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

require_once "../magento/app/Mage.php";

Mage::app('default');

umask(0);

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

var_dump(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()); 
// print true

if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
     $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
      echo $customerData->getId();
      // return customer's id
}
```